# Suppose p has the property that for any a, b ∈ Z, if p divides ab, then p divides a or p divides b. Is p prime? (p is integer and bigger than 1)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

To solve this question, I tried to prove the contraposition of the above statement is true, and then the original statement is also true.
Here is my solution.

Original statement: For all p in **Z**, if {if p divides ab, p divides a or p divides b}, then p is prime.

Contrapositive: If p is not prime, then there exists p in **Z** such that {p divides ab, but p doesn't divide both a and b}

For example, when p=12(composite), ab=24, a =6 and b=4, 12 divides 24, but 12 doesn't divide both 6 and 4.

Therefore, this contraposition is true, and the original statement is also true. QED

What I am concerned about my solution is the first part. I don't actually know whether I can interpret the question like as my original statement since there are two "if~, then~" types of propositions.

There are probably other mistakes.

Please check whether this solution is correct, and if you don't mind, please show me some hints or alternative solutions.

Additional information;
I am first-year student of math, so I only know this is related to Euclid's lemma, and I cannot understand further difficult theorems and so forth.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) You should restrict to $p\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{-1,0,1\}.$ 2) Your contrapositive shouldn't begin with "If p is not prime, then there exists p". 3) An example is useless. You must prove the statement for *every* integer $p\ne-1,0,1.$ 4) If you choose to prove the contrapositive, you must first explicit the non-primality of $p$, i.e. $p$ is *equal to* (hence a fortiori divides) the product of two integers $\ne\pm1$, and then check that $p$ doesn't divide $a$ nor $b.$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In an Integral Domain, every prime is an irreducible. Flaw in the Proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881384/in-an-integral-domain-every-prime-is-an-irreducible-flaw-in-the-proof) But beware the descrepancy of vocabulary: the usual "prime" numbers are called here "irreducible" elements, and what is called here "prime" is your other property.

Comment: Anne Bauval; Firstly for (1), this is actually a question from my assignment, and it says p is integer and bigger than 1. Secondly, for (2)and (3), why is it "for every" integer p?

Comment: 1): in your title you mensionned $p>1,$ but in your body ("Original statement") you only wrote $p\in\Bbb Z$. 2) and 3): You are asked to prove that $A(p)\implies B(p)$ (or equivalently $\neg B(p)\implies\neg A(p)$) for *every* integer $p>1.$

Comment: The source that you posted is definitely beyond my level, and I cannot understand what it says. If it is possible, please show me something that is provable by first year student,

Comment: 1): this is my fault, Thanks for correction. 2): I am understanding that negation of "if a is true, then b is true" is "a is true, and there exist b such that b is not true". Is this right?

Comment: "there exists b" may not make sense. "If I fall into the pool, then I get wet." You would negate it as "I fall into the pool, and there is a "I get wet" such that I don't get wet". The negation of "If a is true, then b is true" is "a is true and b is false." Exactly how to phrase "b is false" depends on what b says. If b is of the form "for all x `blah`", then the negation would be "there exists an x for which not(`blah`)". But if b is of the form "there is an x such that `blah`", then the negation would be "for all x, not(`blah`)". Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek to prove that, for any $p \in \mathbb{Z}^+ - \{1\}$, if $p \mid ab \implies p \mid a$ or $p\mid b$, for every $\{a, b\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, then $p$ is prime.

The contrapositive to such a statement would be, as you correctly stated, that, if $p$ is *not* a prime, then there must be $\{a, b\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p \mid ab$, but $p \nmid a$ and $p \nmid b$.

The example you provide also is correct. However, an example by itself is not sufficient to prove the contrapositive. What you would need to show is that *every* non-prime $p$ verifies that there are $\{a, b\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p \mid ab$ but $p \nmid a$ and $p \nmid b$. Currently, you have only provided a single *example* of a non-prime that verifies such a property.

In my opinion, the main result you could make use of would be the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (i.e., prime decomposition). Shortly stated, it tells you that every positive integer $n$ ($>1$) can be decomposed into a product of powers of $k$ primes. That is, for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ - \{1\}$, there exist $\{p_1, \dots, p_k\} \subset \mathbb{P}$ ($\mathbb{P}$ here the set of primes) and $\{n_1, \dots, n_k\} \subset \mathbb{Z}^+$ so that

$n = p_1^{n_1} \dots \ p_k^{n_k} = \prod_{i = 1}^k p_i^{n_i}$.

Thus, suppose $p$ a non-prime divides $ab$ an integer. As $p$ is $>1$ and division is irrespective of sign, we can consider, without any loss of generality, both $a$ and $b$ to be $>1$ (clearly, if we could not "get down" to such a form —say if $a$ were always $=1$—, then we would be left with $p$ a non-prime dividing $b$ a prime).

Now, as $ab$ is a positive integer ($>1$), we can decompose it into the product of its prime factors. Say, $ab = p_1^{n_1} \dots \ p_k^{n_k}$, with $k > 1$.

Thus, $p \ | \ p_1^{n_1}(p_2^{n_2} \dots \ p_k^{n_k})$ (we can assume $k$ to be $>2$ as otherwise $p$ would divide the product of —powers of— two primes, and would be left with no choice but to be a prime itself). Hence, $p \ | \ p_1^{n_1}$ or $p \ | \ p_2^{n_2} \dots \ p_k^{n_k}$. If the former were the case, $p$ would no doubt be a prime, thus it must be that $p \ | \ p_2^{n_2} \dots \ p_k^{n_k}$.

We can, however, immediately see the problem here. Such an argument can be iterated yet again, and again. The "partitioning" into two parts of the products considered must eventually come to an end, as $k$ itself is finite. When such happens, we will be left with one of two choices: (1) $p$ did not divide any of the partitioned components, in which case the very hypothesis we were working off (i.e., that $p$ would always divide —at least one— of the components) would fail; or (2) $p$ did divide some component $p_j^{n_j}$, in which case our hypothesis that $p$ was non-prime also fails.

As either case leads to an insoluble contradiction, we can only but conclude that $p$ must have been a prime to begin with. $\square$

Comment: `\mid` will produce the vertical line with space around it, so you don't have to type `\ |\ `. Likewise, `\nmid` will produce $\nmid$, which works much better than `\not\mid`, which MathJax (and LaTeX) don't always overlay correctly.

Comment: Thanks for such a brilliant example of this proof. But I still unsure about your reasoning. Did you use proof by contradiction to prove what statement? I am so confused too be honestly, and I need further explanation about your logical process.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Many thanks for the comment and recommendation!!

Comment: @YutaAraki No need for thanks, and I am glad you found my answer informative! The proof is by contradiction, yes. Essentially, I am saying: Suppose $p$ verifies that for any $a, b$ integers $p \mid ab \implies p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$ *but $p$ is not a prime*. Then [contradiction follows as $p$ must either not actually divide one of the components of the product —going against the first hypothesis— or (as each component is a power of a prime) it must actually be a prime —going against the second]. I hope this helps clarify the idea!

Comment: Can't you just take $ab = p$ where $a,b\neq1$, and then $p|a$ and $p|b$ are impossible because $p > a,b$ but $p=ab$ so $p|ab$?

Comment: @CommandMaster I believe that works also!

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @CommandMaster That also explains nicely that the correct conclusion is “… then p is prime or p=1”.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p|ab$ & $p\nmid a,b $. Using bezout identities, $pn_1+an_2=(p,a)$ & $pm_1+bm_2=(p,b)$. Multiplying these equations, we get $pr_1+abr_2=(p,a).(p,b)$ where $r_1,r_2,n_1,n_2,m_1,m_2∈Z$. We know that $p|ab ⟹ [(p,ab)=p] → p|[(p,a).(p,b)]$.

But, we know $p \nmid (p,a)$ and $p \nmid  (p,b)$, hence $p \not \in P$.

You can also refer alternative proofs of the statement from [If prime $p \mid ab$, then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b\ $ [Euclid's Lemma]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162373/1233641)

Thank you

Comment: Can you please tell how to solve the inverse of your proposition?

Comment: Use `\nmid` to get $\nmid$

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what you meant by (p,a). If this is just a symbol of showing pn1+an2, what is (p,ab)=p showing? please explain this. It maybe because I learnt in the different way.

Comment: Its GCD of p and a, $(p,ab) = p$ means that the GCD of p and ab is p.

Comment: @Yuta Araki You can also refer https://brilliant.org/wiki/bezouts-identity/ for understanding bezout's identity.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to know how I can derive the inverse of your proof since that is what I want to find as showing that contrapositive is true.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).